# GNOME broken after 16.04 LTS to 18.04 Bionic Beaver upgrade in Virtualbox on Windows 7 host

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 18.04, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 workstation and I use Virtualbox to run Ubuntu. This is with UI not a headless deal. I try to keep Virtualbox itself and all the Ubuntu packages up to date. I have Virtualbox 5.2.18, currently the latest version available. However my VM image was first created almost 4 years ago and regularly upgraded all this time, even through different Ubuntu dist upgrades.

Today I was offered a release upgrade from 16.04 LTS to **18.04.1 LTS** (Bionic Beaver). I saved a snapshot and proceeded with the upgrade.  When asked whether to remove obsolete packages, whether I do or not, the result is the same.  Afterwards it reboots, and the GNOME desktop environment will not start.  It attempts five times, each time with the Virtualbox window assuming the pre-upgrade dimensions, but each time returning to the console without ever showing the login splash screen.  The final console message is:

> `[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.`

There is other output on the same line, where it appears a CR without LF was done:

> `[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.eport generation.......ystem change.pp link was shut down..`

I am able to switch to another tty and login using Ctrl+Alt+F2, and I can get root, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for to troubleshoot this.  I'm not an expert with GNOME or X.  I will provide in edits any info asked for in comments.

To be clear, *the VM configuration works just fine* before the upgrade to Bionic Beaver.  These VM config options seem like they might be relevant:

- OS profile type = "Linux" and version = "Ubuntu (64-bit)"
- chipset = PIIX3
- I/O APIC is enabled
- EFI (special OS only) is disabled
- 2 CPUs in VM (host has 4) with PAE/NX enabled
- paravirtualization interface = "Legacy" (switching to "Default" or "KVM" does not seem to fix the issue by itself, though the 16.04 snapshot works fine with any of these options)
- VT-X is enabled
- nested paging is enabled
- 3d video acceleration is enabled

Is there any path forward with this upgrade that can restore the graphical environment?  I would prefer not to start over and install clean, as that would be a major inconvenience and will cost substantial time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually an **18.04.2 LTS** version was offered that did not have this issue.  My VirtualBox install is now fully upgraded and working properly.